# Failing SSH login due to "pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user"

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, sftp

I've mounted an s3 bucket to a small ec2 instance and am able to SSH into the instance either via the CLI or using a client like cyberduck.

However, using the same host and credentials I am not able to establish in the Web UI of a data provder in order to upload data to the EC2 instance.

Running `journalctl -u sshd.service` I am able to see the log files.

```
Jul 05 18:14:46 Accepted password for user from 146.52.120.144 port 56303 ssh2
Jul 05 18:14:46 pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user(uid=1001) by (uid=0)
Jul 05 18:15:42 Accepted password for user from 37.61.216.61 port 40684 ssh2
Jul 05 18:15:42 pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user(uid=1001) by (uid=0)
Jul 05 18:15:42 pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user user
```

The first session opened from `146.52.120.144` is the successfull one using cyberduck. The second one is from the data provider. The session immediately closes after accepting the password and opening.

I would appreciate any help in fixing this situation

Comment: Can you show the output of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`  found on your ec2 instance. It seems like there might be a MaxStartups or MaxSessions setting preventing you to  log in.